# Is there a way to use API key for some endpoint and use OAuth2 for other endpoint in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, api-key

I need to secure some endpoint with Google OAuth2 and secure some other endpoint with an API key.

Before I add ApiKeyFilter to AuthConfig, it works as expected. However, when I add the filter, I found the `"/secured-with-api-key/**"` and `"/non-secured/**"` works as expected, but the `"/secured/**"` can be accessed even without the JWT token.

This is the ApiKeyAuthFilter:

```java
public class ApiKeyAuthFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {
private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ApiKeyAuthFilter.class);

    private final String apiKeyHeaderName;
    private final String timestampHeaderName;
    private final String signatureHeaderName;
    
    public ApiKeyAuthFilter(String apiKeyHeaderName, String timestampHeaderName, String signatureHeaderName) {
        this.apiKeyHeaderName = apiKeyHeaderName;
        this.timestampHeaderName = timestampHeaderName;
        this.signatureHeaderName = signatureHeaderName;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String apiKey = request.getHeader(apiKeyHeaderName);
        String timestamp = request.getHeader(timestampHeaderName);
        String signature = request.getHeader(signatureHeaderName);
        return new AuthPrincipal(apiKey, timestamp, signature);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {
        // No creds when using API key
        return null;
    }
```

This is the SimpleAuthenticationManager:

```java
@Component
public class SimpleAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleAuthenticationManager.class);

    @Autowired
    private ApiKeysDatabase apiKeysDatabase;

    @Autowired
    private TokenVerifier tokenVerifier;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

        AuthPrincipal principal = (AuthPrincipal) authentication.getPrincipal();
        if (principal.getApikey() == null || principal.getTimestamp() == null || principal.getSignature() == null) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("The API_KEY/timestamp/signature Header is missing.");
        }
        if (!apiKeysDatabase.isValidKey(principal.getApikey())) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("The API key was not found or not the expected value.");
        }
        if (!tokenVerifier.isTokenAuthorized(principal)) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("The signature is invalid");
        }
        authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

This is the AuthConfig:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class AuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String API_KEY_HEADER_NAME = "API_KEY";
    private static final String TIMESTAMP_HEADER_NAME = "timestamp";
    private static final String SIGNATURE_HEADER_NAME = "signature";

    @Autowired
    private SimpleAuthenticationManager simpleAuthenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        ApiKeyAuthFilter filter = new ApiKeyAuthFilter(API_KEY_HEADER_NAME, TIMESTAMP_HEADER_NAME, SIGNATURE_HEADER_NAME);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(simpleAuthenticationManager);

        http.antMatcher("/secured/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured/**")
                .fullyAuthenticated();

        http.antMatcher("/non-secured/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/non-secured/**")
                .permitAll();

        http.antMatcher("/secured-with-api-key/**")
                .addFilter(filter)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/secured-with-api-key/**")
                .authenticated();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

        http.cors().and().csrf().disable();

        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
    }
}
```

I expected `"/secured/**"` needs JWT to access, `"/secured-with-api-key/**"` needs an API key to access and `"/non-secured/**"` can be accessed by anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Use two `SecurityFilterChain` @Beans: one with resource-server configuration (OAuth2, secured with Bearer access-tokens) and an other one for API key. Don't forget to order the two and limit the first loaded one with `securityMatcher`.

For instance, with filter-chain dedicated to API-key (all routes starting with `/secured-with-api-key/`) and a default one secured with OAuth2 (all routes which didn't match previous filter-chains):

```java
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain apiKeyFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.securityMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/secured-with-api-key/**"));
        // more API key security conf
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) {
        http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        // resource-server security conf
        return http.build();
    }
```